Can't inherit / associatedisk TimeMachine backups (APFS) from a reformatted external drive
I had to reformat an external raid drive (called Joshua) after expanding its size.  After reformatting it, I restored it from our TM drive (called Moses).  However once everything is copied over and I go to back it up, TM wants to call the new drive Joshua 1, and of course take up the full space of the drive.
I should mention at this point, that we are on a 2023 MacMini M2 Pro, with Sonoma 14.5.  This seems to be significant because the recent versions of MacOS format a TM drive as APFS by default.  For some reason, inheritbackup and associatedisk do not work with APFS, or if they do, it is not well documented.
Inheriting Time Machine Backup: Invalid Target mentions a way to resolve moving time machine from one Mac to another.  This case is somewhat different in that I am "merely" trying to get TM to recognize the "Old" Joshua backup as being the same as the "New" Joshua's data.
As this other post suggests trying, I got the extended metadata from the respective folders so that hopefully I can write new metadata.  For some reason, though if I put xattr -l /volumes/Joshua into terminal, it does not give me any metadata.  Not sure if I am doing it wrong, or if Joshua simply doesn't have any metadata.
I put the UUID metadata from the TM backups into a spreadsheet (I have two backups that I pulled data from; and a third backup that I am keeping offline for safety reasons.) I can't seem to bring the screenshot in, but com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeUUID are identical for the old Joshua between Moses and OffsiteBackup.  I thought I found what I needed; however, the com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeUUID for the new Joshua are different for Moses and OffsiteBackup.
My ultimate goal is to get Moses (and the other offsite backups) to associate the "new" Joshua with the backup data for the "old" Joshua.

I have not been able to get inheritbackup or associatedisk to work; and my research indicates that this is due to the TM drives using APFS.  Is this correct?

Is com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeUUID the "magical" metadata that I need to change to get Moses to recognize the "new" Joshua in place of the "old"?  Or is there something else?  And how do I get xattr to show me what the metadata for the new /Volumes/Joshua?


TM will be busy restoring data for most of the weekend, but I'll be monitoring this post over the weekend.  Thank you for any help you can give.

Bearing in mind the success achieved by the answer below, were you able to successfully complete your restore? It might be worth updating the question with the commands used, and the errors received when you attempted to use associatedisk and inheritbackup.

To associate a new disk "Develop" with my old "Develop_Backup" TM, i.e. to continue backing up after the latest backup on 2024-12-12-205101, I had to run:
sudo tmutil associatedisk "/Volumes/Develop" "/Volumes/Develop_Backup/2024-12-12-205101.previous/Develop"


While your answer addresses that associatedisk works for you, does your answer provide anymore information to the OP to help solve their problem? If you can give any more insight into the differences in experience, please feel free to update your answer.

OP here.  Basically I asked this question several months ago, hoping to get an answer that weekend.  Failing that, I basically trashed the old one and kept the rebuilt backup (to preserve space on the backup drive).  Looking at the answer, I do not see that it was any different than anything that I tried.  However, it's been a while and I've slept since then.  I do have to redo backups every now and then, so I can give it a try next time and report back.  (But it might be several months before I do)
